# Turtlebot moves backwards

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm following this tutorial on sending simple goals to the Turtlebot navigation stack;
[SendingSimpleGoals](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals)

When I run the program, the Turtlebot moves in a backwards direction in the sense that, it moves opposite to the direction the Kinect sensor is facing. We've calibrated the gyro and odometry as described in the wiki page but the Turtlebot never seems to move forward (in the direction the Kinect is facing). Whenever we run the program, the Turtlebot rotates a couple of times (creating a map) and then moves in the opposite direction.

Could anyone please provide some assistance as to why this is the problem?

EDIT: Thanks everyone, the kinect was mounted the wrong way around by the people who used it previously and hence why the Turtlebot was moving backwards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111351/turtlebot-moves-backwards/) by [aviprobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/6004/aviprobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-17**:
What happens if you send a direct command velocity of forward only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had got the same problem, the kinect was mounted in a wrong way. I just changed it and all was fine ;-)

---

Originally posted by [MAKL](https://answers.ros.org/users/8106/makl/) with karma: 36 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1